# Mysql how to group by multiple columns, and select a flag value based on which group matched

Tags: mysql

Suppose I want to take all duplicate values of a table by following matched criteria's:
1- matched by (first_name,last_name,father_name).
2- matched by (nationalId).
3- matched by (phone_number).

Suppose I want to get all users whose registered them self more than one using above conditions.
Now i want to take those duplicate records, along the other columns a i need to select a a column `matched_type` that should has one of these `1`,`2`,`3` values based on what matched occurred.
Now i have separate query for each matching criteria, is it possible to do it with one query?

I have these queries:

```
SELECT u.first_name,u.last_name,u.father_name,u.national_id,u.phone,COUNT(u.id) AS total,'1' AS match_type
FROM users
GROUP BY CONCAT(u.first_name,u.last_name,u.father_name)
HAVING total > 1
```

and for second matching criteria:

```
SELECT u.first_name,u.last_name,u.father_name,u.national_id,u.phone,COUNT(u.id) AS total, '2' AS match_type
FROM users
GROUP BY u.national_id
HAVING total > 1
```

and for the last one:

```
SELECT u.first_name,u.last_name,u.father_name,u.national_id,u.phone,COUNT(u.id) AS total, '3' AS match_type
FROM users
GROUP BY u.phone
HAVING total > 1
```

And then i have like this:

```
SELECT src.* FROM (first_query UNION ALL second_query UNION ALL third_query)
```

Comment: Please include your query and data.  As it stands now, this question won't be very helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Can you please add the table structure too?

Answer (score 0):

Pls check is this ok?

```
SELECT first_name,last_name, father_name, nationalId, phone_number ,CASE  
WHEN first_name=[Value] AND last_name=[Value] AND father_name = [VALUE] THEN 1 
  WHEN nationalId=[VALUE] THEN 2
  WHEN phone_number=[VALUE] THEN 3
  ELSE 0 END as matched_type FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE
(first_name=[Value] AND last_name=[Value] AND father_name = [VALUE]) 
OR nationalId=[VALUE] OR phone_number=[VALUE]
```

Comment: But i wan't to take all duplicate, not with specific value.

Comment: I saw that. Thats fine